# Firefox - Show menu bars hidden by window.open

Tags: firefox

Some websites open new browser windows without any UI elements present: no toolbar, no menu bar, etc. The script for opening such window may look as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank","outerWidth=400,outerHeight=200,top=500,left=600,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,personalbar=no,status=no,resizable")
</script>
```

My question is: if such a new window opens in Firefox, is there a way to somehow manually enable all the hidden bars? For example, I want to have all my add-on buttons visible and clickable on this page. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `about:config` section, you can handle how firefox handles the `window.open` parameters. Search for 'dom.disable_window_open_feature' and you can see the list of items you can have firefox ignore. See [this kb](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.disable_window_open_feature.location) for more info on this feature.

[image]

Comment: Consider putting `dom.disable_window_open_feature` as the first option, because copying URL into a new tab won't always work (many scripts in such new windows check `window.opener` and don't work properly if it is empty)

Comment: @Andre Edited and done